# Is this a safe way to disable interrupts on PIC24?

Tags: interrupt, pic, interrupt-handling, pic24

I am working on a project that uses a Microchip PIC24FJ256GA702. For several days I have been looking for an intermittent bug with some UART code. It uses an interrupt service routine (ISR) to transmit a buffer named `char txBuff[]` and its length `int txLen`.

In the main (i.e. not ISR) code I occasionally access the buffer to add bytes or to see how many bytes are left to transmit. To ensure the main code sees a clean copy of the buffer it has a critical section in the form:

```
Disable interrupts
Read and write 'txBuff' and its length 'txLen'
Enable interrupt
```

There are several ways to disable an ISR on this PIC. Including: Use the `DISI` instruction, or clear the `GIE` bit, or alter interrupt priority levels.

But I have chosen to clear the interrupt to enable bit of the specific interrupt bit in `IECx`. In this case, it is IEC1bits.U2TXIE because I am using UART2. I do this because it is easy, it does not disable unrelated interrupts, and it has always worked well in my other projects. So in C, the critical section is:

```
IEC1bits.U2TXIE = 0;
copyOfTxLen = txLen;
...
IEC1bits.U2TXIE = 1;
```

And the disassembly listing starts:

```
 BCLR 0x9B, #7 // disable interrupt
 MOV txLen, W1 // read txLen
...
```

**The problem**: I am now fairly certain that the ISR occasionally gets called during `read txLen` such that `copyOfTxLen` ends up being the value of `txLen` before the ISR was called, but the remainder of the critical section sees variables in the state they are after the ISR is called.

**The question**: Is my code faulty? If so how can the fault be avoided?

Some background:

- UART is running at a high speed (250 kBaud) with a PIC24 clock of 8 MHz, a byte every 160 instructions, so the ISR is quite busy and this I think increases the chances of hitting a race condition compared to my previous projects.
- I see [dsPIC33/PIC24 Family Reference Manual / Interrupts](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70000600d.pdf), section 2.3.1 Note 2 says "There is one cycle delay between clearing the GIE bit and the interrupts being disabled." Now this refers to `GIE`, not `U2TXIE` and I am not sure whether it would cause a problem like I am seeing because the `MOV` instruction is a 2 cycle instruction. But nevertheless, it looks like a cunning way to trap unwary programmers.
- If I try to debug it or add any debug code the already very intermittent problem goes away (feels like a race condition). I don't want to just add some `NOP`s without knowing exactly why I should because race conditions always bite you back unless you actually fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question *is* faulty.
To fix it, wrap expressions intended to disable interrupts such as `IEC1bits.U2TXIE = 0` in a macro like this:

```
__write_to_IEC(IEC1bits.U2TXIE = 0);
```

[XC16 compiler release notes](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Readme_XC16_131.html) says:

> `__write_to_IEC(X)` - a macro that wraps the expression X with an appropriate number of nop instructions to ensure that the write to the `IEC` register has taken effect before the program executes. For example, `__write_to_IEC(IEC0bits.T1IE = 0);` will not progress until the device has disabled the interrupt enable bit for T1 (Timer1).

In `p24FJ256GA702.h` that is provided with the XC16 compiler, the macro is defined:

```
#define __write_to_IEC(X) \
   ( (void)(X), \
     __builtin_nop() \
   )
```

So despite not being mentioned anywhere in the [PIC24FJ256GA705 FAMILY datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC24FJ256GA705-Family-Data-Sheet-DS30010118E.pdf) or in the [separate Interrupts document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/dsPIC33-PIC24-FRM,-Interrupts-DS70000600E.pdf), it seems clear that a single `NOP` is required here on this PIC.

Update: I find exactly the same issue on the dsPIC33EP256MU806 (dsPIC33E family) which requires two `NOP` instructions.